# Binding an event to a command in a viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, command

I just started writing my own small state chart editor. I wanted it to be in the MVVM pattern.
But I got problems with binding events to commands in the viewmodel.

When running my application this InvalidCastException appears.

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'.

I have the following snippet in my xaml file.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:StateViewModel x:Key="StateViewModel"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource StateViewModel}">
    <Rectangle MouseLeftButtonDown="{Binding Path=DragStartCommand}">
</Grid>
```

In my StateViewModel I created the ICommand property.

```
    private DelegateCommand _dragStartCommand;
    public ICommand DragStartCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dragStartCommand == null)
            {
                _dragStartCommand = new DelegateCommand(StartDragging);
            }
            return _dragStartCommand;
        }
    }

    private void StartDragging(object obj)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

and the DelegateCommand class looks like the following

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me fix the problem. 
In order to this it would be nice to know how I can pass the EventArgs to my command and use them.

Comment: where abouts does the error occur, on what line?

Comment: it occurs in the root tag of my UserControl

Answer (score 0):

you can use the EventToCommand Behavior from blend sdk

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 


<DataGrid>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
         <Commanding:EventToCommand  Command="{Binding Path=OpenCommand}" 
                                     CommandParameter="{Binding YourParameterBindingGoesHereIfYouNeedIt}"/>
       </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

or you look into MVVMLight there is also such an behavior

Comment: this would have been my next step, if i can't find a solution without blend

Comment: @blindmeis do you know why Commanding in  Commanding:EventToCommand becomes red and VS complains that it doesn't know this part? I have used the same namespace as you do.

Comment: I got SilverLight from Tools<NuGet.